# What is Custom FileProvider Path in Flutter Social Share Plugin?

Tags: xml, flutter, android-xml, flutter-plugin

I'm using this flutter social share plugin : [appinio_social_share](https://pub.dev/packages/appinio_social_share)

I have problem with the following code in AndroidXML:

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" 
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.[your_custom_fileProvider_path]"
android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/[your_custom_fileProvider_file_name]" />
```

What is this "your_custom_fileProvider_path"? Do I need to create a custom fileProvide class in android native code in order to use this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create xml folder and add a provider path file to it (for example: provider_paths_app.xml) in android/app/src/main/res and add the lines below to the created xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Later when you do this you change the `[your_custom_fileProvider_path]` to your fileProvider path and it should work

Comment: So if I created a xml file and named it provider_path.xml then I should replace [your_custom_fileProvider_path] with provider_path? There are 2 custom fields need to be filled - [your_custom_fileProvider_path] and  @xml/[your_custom_fileProvider_file_name]. I believe the provider_path should go to xml/[your_custom_fileProvider_file_name] and most of the example I've seen they filed [your_custom_fileProvider_path] with package name like com.myapp.util.provider. why that's the case?